# How to tansfrom row data into column data format using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the below format.

**Input**

```
From    To  Zone 1  Zone 2  Zone 3  Zone 4  Zone 5
10.1    20  0.45    0.45    0.35    0.45    0.45
20.1    40  0.45    0.45    0.45    0.45    0.70
40.1    50  0.50    0.50    0.55    0.55    0.55
50.1    250 0.75    0.79    0.79    0.80    0.79
```

**Desired Output**

```
From    To  Kg  Attribute   Value
10.1    20  0.5 Zone 1          0.45
10.1    20  0.5 Zone 2          0.45
10.1    20  0.5 Zone 3          0.35
10.1    20  0.5 Zone 4          0.45
10.1    20  0.5 Zone 5          0.45
20.1    40  0.5 Zone 1          0.45
20.1    40  0.5 Zone 2          0.45
20.1    40  0.5 Zone 3          0.45
20.1    40  0.5 Zone 4          0.45
20.1    40  0.5 Zone 5          0.70
```

How can this be done in pandas python?

Comment: `df.melt(['From','To'], var_name='Attribute').assign(Kg=0.5)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, `kg`will differ across the dataset.

Comment: What do you mean? There's no mention of `Kg` in your original dataset.

Comment: @QuangHoang,  Sorry got confused.

Comment: @QuangHoang, Hey your correct, I got lost. Thanks it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set From and To as index and use stack().

```
(
    df.set_index(['From', 'To']).stack().to_frame('Value')
    .rename_axis(['From', 'To', 'Attribute'])
    .assign(Kg=0.5)
    .reset_index()
)

    From    To  Attribute   Value   Kg
0   10.1    20  Zone1   0.45    0.5
1   10.1    20  Zone2   0.45    0.5
2   10.1    20  Zone3   0.35    0.5
3   10.1    20  Zone4   0.45    0.5
4   10.1    20  Zone5   0.45    0.5
5   20.1    40  Zone1   0.45    0.5
6   20.1    40  Zone2   0.45    0.5
7   20.1    40  Zone3   0.45    0.5
8   20.1    40  Zone4   0.45    0.5
9   20.1    40  Zone5   0.70    0.5
10  40.1    50  Zone1   0.50    0.5
11  40.1    50  Zone2   0.50    0.5
12  40.1    50  Zone3   0.55    0.5
13  40.1    50  Zone4   0.55    0.5
14  40.1    50  Zone5   0.55    0.5
15  50.1    250 Zone1   0.75    0.5
16  50.1    250 Zone2   0.79    0.5
17  50.1    250 Zone3   0.79    0.5
18  50.1    250 Zone4   0.80    0.5
19  50.1    250 Zone5   0.79    0.5
```